# ASP GridView All Rows In Edit Mode

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In my ASP.NET page, I'm using a GridView to view data (Items & their prices). Currently users can edit the data (prices) in the grid row by row. (Click --> "Edit" link, change the values then "Update"). This is ROW by ROW. Is it possible to open all rows in Edit mode & use a single button (eg. Submit) to update all data once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need to read only mode, in that case you can put input boxes ( textbox, dropdownlist, etc.) in `ItemTEmplate` section and bind them with existing data.

Next, put a submit button at above/below of the GridView and handle button `Click` event and loop through the `GridView` item data and save all database.

I'll post code block if you need. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I am having the same issue for my gridview. Is it possible for you to post the code for the button click event??

Answer (score 0):

And you will have better control on that you doing by using listview instead of gridview.

My best practise is using listview and custom web user control for this kind of problems.

If you fill your listview with your user control, you will easy to manage your saving method, just have to iterate on the listview items, find control and call your Save() method for each item.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question has already been answered but here is the code for loop through the GridView getting data and store it in the Data Base:

Using libraries:

- using System.Data;
- using System.Data.SqlClient;
- using System.Web.Configuration;
- using System.Data.Odbc;

Code Behind:

```
// this is a variable that have the Query or SQL Commands.
string DataBaseQuery = "UPDATE [table] SET [variable2] = @variable2, [variable3] = @variable3) WHERE [variable1] = @variable1";

//Click Event from a LinkButton.
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //"ConnectionString" its the string connection for your DataBase (often get from the WebConfig File or a DataSource element.
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
  {
    //this is for open the database using the string connection.
    connection.Open(); 

    //this is the algorithm for going through the entire GridView.
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
      //"DataBaseQuery" it's a string variable that have the Query or SQL Commands.
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(DataBaseQuery, conexion);

      //this case it's for obtain the text variable of the first column of the gridview (in my case it was the ID of the register).
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variable1", ((Label)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("Label1")).Text.ToString());

      //this case it's for obtain the selected value of a DropDownList that were in the 14 th column)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variable2", ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[15].FindControl("DropDownlist2")).SelectedValue.ToString());

      //this command it's for obtain the text of a textbox that is in the 15 th column of the gridview.
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variable3", ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[16].FindControl("TextBox17")).Text.ToString());

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }

    //after going through all the gridview you have to close the connection to the DataBase.
    connection.Close();
  }
}
```

Of course you have to adjust the code to your particular case but it's very easy. In this code you have the example to obtain values for other object like labes, textbox and dropdownlist in the gridview.

I suffered a lot to make run this code (I'm not good programming) but I'm happy to help.

NOTE: For count the columns of the gridview you have to start at zero. 
NOTE2: Sorry for my bad English by the way... It's not my nature language.